# Can we run embedded Kafka broker like ActiveMQ?

Tags: apache-kafka, activemq-classic, spring-kafka, confluent-platform

When I say embedded this what I mean please refer to following thread - https://stackoverflow.com/a/28858630/5375223

Let me give some context, in our project we are currently using ActiveMQ as messaging broker and now we are planning to migrate to Kafka. Please see the attached picture.

[image]

Like in above diagram, producer sends data to embedded broker and, then embedded broker sends data to external broker which are connected via network url configuration like below. So, if the external broker is not available all the messages will sit in embedded broker until its available.

```
<networkConnectors>
    <networkConnector name="localhost" uri="static://somehost:1234" staticBridge="true">
        <staticallyIncludedDestinations>
            <queue physicalName="someQueueName"/>
        </staticallyIncludedDestinations>
    </networkConnector>
</networkConnectors>
```

So, is there anyway to do like this with Kafka? instead of directly connecting to broker running outside the application

Comment: See this? I think it requires enterprise version, though.  https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jms/kafka-connect-activemq/docs/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Spring for Apache Kafka provides an embedded broker, but it's mainly intended to be used for testing.

<s>There's nothing built into kafka to "forward" records from one broker (embedded or otherwise) to another; you'd need some code to do that.</s>

What is the purpose of doing that anyway? Why not just send directly to the external broker?

Regardless, Kafka is designed for use with multiple nodes and multiple zookeeper instances to provide resiliency and prevent data loss, so relying on a single local instance would likely reduce or eliminate that.

Comment: *There's nothing built into kafka to "forward" records from one broker (embedded or otherwise) to another* -- Umm, Kafka Connect is "built-in" to the Kafka library. MirrorMaker is used to send between Kafka clusters